# Admin is showing all posts on page 1

Tags: posts, wp-admin, pagination

I have 900 media items on the site. For some reason the pagination has stopped working in a few sites and all the posts are being shown slowing down the site a lot. This happens on the Media library (/wp-admin/upload.php) and admin Posts list page too (/wp-admin/edit.php).

I've disabled all plugins. Posts per page is set as 20 via settings > reading.

I'm printing the query using a pre_get_posts - print_r($wp_query); and its says posts per page = 20.

Seems like the posts per page is getting messed up somehow? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something in your theme that's interfering?

Comment: i've had a good look and i'm certain the only theme file that can affect the admin is the functions.php. And i've searched theme wide for a posts_per_page setting. And at the top of the admin page that's showing ALL of the items its says in the spat out $wp-query 'posts_per_page' =>20.

Comment: You could try a default theme, just to be sure (remember to backup first) or you might have mu-plugins ?

Comment: Did you check your Screen Options for the media and posts page? It's the small tab in the upper right of the screen that readds "Screen Options", clicking on it will reveal a form that allows you to configure the number of items displayed on that page.

Comment: screen options say 20 too.

Comment: @birgire - just done that and the problem goes with another theme. I think its the pre_get_posts. It doesn't have a ppp set but maybe if its not it wipes it out.

Comment: good to hear you found the problem and remember to accept your answer to close the question @danielCrabbe

Answer (score 0):

so it was `$wp_query->set('nopaging', true);`

Which was set in a `pre_get_posts` function. I never thought of searching for this.

I've added

```
if(!is_admin()){
// code
}
```

So it doesn't run in the admin.